# v8: Exact Meaning of the SideEffektType Property when creating Functions

Tags: c++, v8

When creating a new `Function<T>` from c++, v8 asks for the `SideEffektType` of the C callback.

This is described as `Options for marking whether callbacks may trigger JS-observable side effects.` in v8.h.
Observable side effekt still leaves a lot to guess here. For example, if you implement a function that prints to `std::cout`, there is no JS observable side effekt, but you still don't want the compiler to reoder or omit calls to that function.

Another question is how to flag our functions if getters and setters for a c-object are exported as js-functions. They do have an observable side effekt - omitting or reodering could break the semantics - but they do not change the current stack frame or any global variables, leaving v8 with a lot of optimization potential.

We'd love to know how this property is used inside v8, as this should help to answer which flag to use for each function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, look at the documentation of the SideEffectType enum:

```
/**
 * Options for marking whether callbacks may trigger JS-observable side effects.
 * Side-effect-free callbacks are whitelisted during debug evaluation with
 * throwOnSideEffect. It applies when calling a Function, FunctionTemplate,
 * or an Accessor callback. For Interceptors, please see
 * PropertyHandlerFlags's kHasNoSideEffect.
 * Callbacks that only cause side effects to the receiver are whitelisted if
 * invoked on receiver objects that are created within the same debug-evaluate
 * call, as these objects are temporary and the side effect does not escape.
 */
```

So it's not about optimization potential. (Rest assured that V8 knows about ordering requirements between reading and writing properties; no special annotations are needed for that.)

So, in other words:

- if you have a getter (where you don't care how often it's called), mark it `kHasNoSideEffect`
- if you have a setter that (as setters usually do) writes a property of the receiver object, mark it `kHasSideEffectToReceiver`
- if you have a function that does some other thing that you don't want repeated (changing global variables, creating database entries, etc) mark it `kHasSideEffect`. A function that prints to `std::cout` probably also falls into this bucket, but it's up to you to decide how you feel about potentially spamming your `std::cout` log. If you don't use debug-evaluation, you won't even see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

These flags are used by the v8 debugger protocol to decide if it is safe to eagerly evaluate an input.

If an input is determined to have no side effects it can be shown before you press enter in debuggers:

[image: eager evaluation of "1 + 1"]

Here, the input would mutate `a`, and therefore have a side effect. As you can see, `a.push(2)` is not evaluated.

[image: no eager evaluation of "Array.prototype.push"]

> For example, if you implement a function that prints to std::cout, there is no JS observable side effekt, but you still don't want the compiler to reoder or omit calls to that function.

As such, you can decide for yourself what you consider to be a side effect, and v8 will obey you.